# ObjectQuery<T>.Include Method returns parent instances that have child instances only

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, include

I have the following entities:

```
public class Parent
{
    ...

    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class Child
{
    public Int32 ParentID { get; set; }
    public Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I've created the mapping between these entities as the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().HasRequired(child => child.Parent)
           .WithMany(parent => parent.Children)
           .HasForeignKey(child => child.ParentID);
```

I am trying to load `Child` instances as I load `Parent` instances using [ObjectQuery.Include Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx). have the following statement:

```
DBContext.Set<Parent>().Include(instance => instance.Children);
```

The statement returns `Parent` instances only where `Parent` have some `Child` instances. I need to return the full list.

Appreciate your help :)

Comment: Isn't that the statement should have returned the full list even though there is no children?

Comment: @Yuliam Chandra: It is indeed a strange behavior.